# Python return two separate objects in one 'return'

Tags: python, django

Is it possible to return two separate object in one 'return' statement? I have tried below but I get 'tuple' object.

```
recipient, user = authenticate(mobile=mobile, email=email)
```

Function:

```
def authenticate(self, mobile=None, email=None):
     user = Recipient.objects.recipient_friend_match(mobile, email)
     return user[0], user
```

Comment: Unpack the tuple: `x, y = function()`.

Comment: is that not what I'm doing here: recipient, user =

Comment: You can only ever return one thing, but that one thing can be a `tuple`, which you can unpack at the call site (i.e. what you're doing with `recipient, user `).

Comment: so can I do this: return user[0], user ?

Comment: Your code should work, but why return `user[0]` separately when it's already included in `user`?

Comment: one is a list of users, where authenticate needs 1 user returned as it adds stuff to it 'backend' or something and won't work with a list.

Comment: Ok, I see now. yep it does work. It seems tho it's not possible to use authenticate() and then login() as it does special stuff when returning a user. I know that was not my question, but is the reason for the error above and why I assumed it was not working. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

return tuple is right,you can get them like this

```
def fun():
    a = 4
    b = [1,2,3,4]
    return a,b # equals to return (a,b)

a,b=fun()
```

just print a and b to see the results

Comment: if more,like this,  a,b,c,d,e = [1,2,3,4,5] # or (1,2,3,4,5)

Answer (score 0):

or you can use dict like this

```
def fun():
    a = 1
    b = 2
    return dict(x=a, y=b)
```